# How to refresh page for new request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to receive a request.POST values N times, where N is a number entered by the user. The views.py is:

```py
def valores(request):
    global peso_unitario, preco_unitario
    peso_unitario = []
    preco_unitario = []

    N = a
    print('N=' + str(N))

    for i in range(N):
        form = Form(request.POST)
        c = int(request.POST.get('peso_u'))
        d = int(request.POST.get('preco_u'))
        peso_unitario.append(c)
        preco_unitario.append(d)

        return render(request, 'valores.html')
    return render(request, 'pacote_m.html', {'peso_unitario': peso_unitario, 'preco_unitario': preco_unitario})
```

In this code in the end I have two returns, where the first is inside the for loop because I want to receive the values N times and return them to the template `valores.html`. The last return is in the end, after the for loop will redirect to a new template, this template `pacote.html` will show the values calculated according to I programmed, but it isn't the problem.

The template `valores.html` is:

```html
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form action="page2" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h1>Digitados:</h1>
    numero de objetos={{n_objetos}}<br>
    peso peso maximo={{peso_maximo}}<br>

    <!--- Peso unitario: <input type="text" name="peso_u"><br><br>
    Preco unitario: <input type="text" name="preco_u"><br><br> --->


    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Peso unitario</th>
          <th>Preco unitario</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="peso_u"></td>
          {{form.peso_u}}
          <td><input type="text" name="preco_u"></td>
          {{form.preco_u}}
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My forms.py is:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    peso_u = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    preco_u = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The problem is I can't get the `N` request.POST values. I realized that it gets only once the request.POST values, the following requests substitute the values entered before and it will continue in the loop, I realized that the loop is forever because it will request more than `N` times the values, maybe because it substitute the value entered before.

Comment: Your for loop will only run once because it has a `return` statement in it. Why would you want to do this anyway, I'm sure there's a better way of whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Please could you explain what you are trying to make , there may be other ways for sending request like ajax , websocket .  I want to know what exactly are you trying to make . Also your loop will only work once because you have return statement in the loop . That just exist the loop and gives out the result .

Comment: Your HTML markup is also invalid (`<tbody>` is never closed and fields are rendered outside of `<td>`, which is weird)

Comment: @OmKashyap I'm trying to make more requests. For example, if the user entered 10, the template valores.html should receive the values 10 times. What do I want? I want in this page the user entering with two values, n_peso and n_preco, the user click in submit and the page "refresh", this refresh that I want is get the values e start a new request. It must repeat 10 times, in case of the example I cited.